# Image over other image Android

Tags: android, bitmap, overlay

How can i set image (semi-trasparent) over other image ?
I need to create new bitmap and then save it.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    Bitmap bitmap1 = null; // define it
    Bitmap bitmap2 = null; // define it

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(resultBitmap);

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, null);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAlpha(127);

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, p);

    // Your final bitmap is resultBitmap
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to take the two bitmaps and set their
bounds. Then you need to draw them both on the canvas. 
If you want to set the image as semi-trasparent, you need to set the alpha of the picture.

This is an example:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Resources res = getResources();


        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.test1); //blue

        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.test2); //green
        Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap1);
        Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap2);


        drawable1.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        drawable2.setBounds(150, 150, 350, 350);
        drawable1.draw(c);
        drawable2.draw(c);


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a canvas object from the bottom layer canvas. Then draw the semi-transparent Bitmap to that canvas. The original Bitmap object will now have the semi-transparent bitmap written on top of it.