# amdroid overlay 1 bitmap to another image not getting proper output

Tags: android, bitmap, overlap, masking

In one of my application i need to do masking( overlapping 1 image to another image)

In my app i have to load 1 image(Bitmap) to imageview then have to apply some fram to that image i have used another imageview for that... this is totally working

My problem is that..
When i am going to save the bitmap...
using this pice of code

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator
                + "test.jpg");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

i am getting  [image: this]

But i need it like

[image: This]

Comment: you need to use Layer Drawable for that

Comment: can you suggest me some link?

Comment: http://myandroidtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2012/09/drawables-part-ii.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#LayerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%5b%5d%29 and Complete example http://jacekdalkowski.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/android-draw-a-number-of-bitmaps-or-drawables-into-a-single-drawable/

Answer (score 1):

The best I found so far is this one:

```
public Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2.getWidth(), bmp2.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        float left =(bmp2.getWidth() - (bmp1.getWidth()*((float)bmp2.getHeight()/(float)bmp1.getHeight())))/(float)2.0;
        float bmp1newW = bmp1.getWidth()*((float)bmp2.getHeight()/(float)bmp1.getHeight());
        Bitmap bmp1new = getResizedBitmap(bmp1, bmp2.getHeight(), (int)bmp1newW);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1new, left ,0 , null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);

    // determine the width of the canvas
    int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();  

    //resize your bmp2
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp2, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, true);

    // determine the centre of the canvas
    int centreX = (canvasWidth  - resized .getWidth()) /2;
    int centreY = (canvasHeight - resized .getHeight()) /2 

   // This code can be used to alter the opacity of the image being overlayed.
   //http://stackoverflow.com/a/12235235/1635441
   //http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119093/1635441        
   //Paint p = new Paint();
   //p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_ATOP)); //http://stackoverflow.com/a/17553502/1635441
   //p.setAlpha(180);
   //p.setARGB(a, r, g, b);

   //canvas.drawBitmap(resized, centreX, centreY, p);  

    //canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resized, centreX, centreY, null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "test.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question? To perform an overlay you require a canvas on which you have to draw the main image and the image that is being used to overlayed. To create the effect that the one image is above the other, the Paint object is used to set the opacity (making the top image more transparent).

Comment: can you suggest me some link for that?

Comment: Please have a look at the code and attempt to implement it in your app, as the code is a fair representation of what you requested above. I am unsure as to why you require a link.

Comment: in your code you have not specified what is overlay ?

Comment: in this lines     int centreX = (canvasWidth  - overlay.getWidth()) /2;
    int centreY = (canvasHeight - overlay.getHeight()) /2 ;

Comment: I apologise, as I misunderstood your reference to overlay. I have since amended the code.

Comment: i mean to say in above two line thare is overlay. then how you initialize this overlay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57142/discussion-between-ramizmoh-and-pragna).